# Cursor count is zero altough data exists in SQLite with Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursor

I want to access data from a SQLite database and I have the following SQLiteOpenHelper Java class (the importnant method is called getData  and is at the very end of the class)

```
package com.example.td.barapp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE = "DrinksDB.db";
    public static final String TABLE_DRINKS = "table_drinks";
    public static final String TABLE_RATINGS = "table_ratings";
    public static final String TABLE_INGREDIENTS = "table_ingredients";
    public static final String TABLE_INGREDIENTS_GERMAN = "table_ingredients_german";

    /*
    Variables for the table "Drinks"
     */
    public static final String DRINK_NAME = "Name";
    public static final String DRINK_NAME_GERMAN = "Name_German";
    public static final String DRINK_TYPE = "Drink_Type";

      /*
     Variables for the table "RATINGS"
     */

    public static final String NUMBER_1STARS = "1_Star";
    public static final String NUMBER_2STARS = "2_Star";
    public static final String NUMBER_3STARS = "3_Star";
    public static final String NUMBER_4STARS = "4_Star";
    public static final String NUMBER_5STARS = "5_Star";

       /*
     Variables for the table "Ingredients"
     */

    public static final String NUMBER_OFINGREDIENTS = "Number Ingredients";
    public static final String INGREDIENT_1 = "Ingredient_1";
    public static final String INGREDIENT_2 = "Ingredient_2";
    public static final String INGREDIENT_3 = "Ingredient_3";
    public static final String INGREDIENT_4 = "Ingredient_4";
    public static final String INGREDIENT_5 = "Ingredient_5";
    public static final String INGREDIENT_6 = "Ingredient_6";
    public static final String INGREDIENT_7 = "Ingredient_7";
    public static final String INGREDIENT_8 = "Ingredient_8";

    public static final String INGREDIENT_1_GERMAN = "Ingredient_1_German";
    public static final String INGREDIENT_2_GERMAN = "Ingredient_2_German";
    public static final String INGREDIENT_3_GERMAN = "Ingredient_3_German";
    public static final String INGREDIENT_4_GERMAN = "Ingredient_4_German";
    public static final String INGREDIENT_5_GERMAN = "Ingredient_5_German";
    public static final String INGREDIENT_6_GERMAN = "Ingredient_6_German";
    public static final String INGREDIENT_7_GERMAN = "Ingredient_7_German";
    public static final String INGREDIENT_8_GERMAN = "Ingredient_8_German";



    public DataBaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_DRINKS + " (Name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, Name_German TEXT, Drink_Type TEXT   ) ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DRINKS);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public boolean insertDataDrinksDB (String name, String nameGerman, String type) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DRINK_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(DRINK_NAME_GERMAN, nameGerman);
        contentValues.put(DRINK_TYPE, type);
        long inserted = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_DRINKS, null, contentValues);

        if (inserted==-1) {
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }

    public Cursor getData (String drinkname) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select " +  DRINK_TYPE +" from " + TABLE_DRINKS + " where "
                + DRINK_NAME + "= ' " + drinkname + "'", null);
        return res;


    }


}
```

In the main activity I want to access data that is in the database by using this class (the important lines are at the end of the onCreateMethod):

```
package com.example.td.barapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.td.barapp.databinding.ActivityMain2Binding;
import com.example.td.barapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

   DataBaseHelper drinksDB;
    private ActivityMain2Binding binding;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        drinksDB = new DataBaseHelper (this);
        boolean insert = drinksDB.insertDataDrinksDB("Orange Juice", "Orangensaft", "Softdrink");

        Cursor res = drinksDB.getData("Orange Juice");
        boolean getCountZero = res.getCount()==0;
        Log.e("LogTag", "CountZero= " + getCountZero);

        String drinkType = res.getString(0);
        Toast.makeText(this, "DrinkType = " + drinkType, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }



}
```

Unfortunately the res.getCount() method provides a count of zero which I do not understand because the query itself is correct when I use it in an SQL database programm with the created database. The other strange aspect is that the call

```
String drinkType = res.getString(0); leads to the error message:

Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
```

It says that I requested index -1 altough the parameter of this method is a 0 (even when I use 20 as a parameter it still says that index - 1 is requested).

Would anyone mind having a look at it and telling me what my mistake is? As said before, the database itself is correct. I'd appreciate every comment and will be quite thankful for your help.

Comment: `"= ' " + drinkname + "'"` - you have an extra space before drinkname (and inside single quote) - so you'll be querying on `' Softdrink'`.  Is that intended?  (In `getData`)

Comment: Thanks Andy. Yes this was a mistake. However I still get the error message by calling 'res.getString(0)' :
"CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1"

Comment: If count > 0 then must do `res.moveToFirst()` before any gets.

Comment: Before `String drinkType = res.getString(0);` you must move the index of the cursor to the 1st row: `res.moveToFirst();` or better: `String drinkType; if (res.moveToFirst()) {drinkType = res.getString(0); Toast.makeText(this, "DrinkType = " + drinkType, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}`

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy and forpas for your answers and great help. Now it works. Do I always have to use "moveToFirst" before I use the getString() method? What If I want to use the getString(0) and getString(1) method two times in succession? Do I have to call moveToFirst before each of those statements?

Comment: When the cursor is created its index is positioned before the 1st row if it exists. So you must call moveToFirst or moveToNext. Both return true or false if they succeed.

Comment: Thanks forpas for your answer. Bascially I do not fully understand it. If I have to call moveToNext every time why do I have to specify an index in the getString method?

Comment: moveToNext() moves the index of the cursor from row to row. Don't confuse it with the index of the getString() method which is used to get the columns by their index. These are 2 different indices.